# Xenserver 6.0 Freezes on Install

Tags: installation, xenserver

I've been trying to get XenServer 5.5 upgraded to 6.0 on my Rackable Systems boxes with Intel S500PSL boards. However when booting the install it freezes when i select an option at the splash screen. I can't get to a shell or to the installer, has anyone experienced this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you cant upgrade from XS 5.5 to 6.0 directly. You have to pass through XS 5.6 first. Check Tobias's answer:
http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=294812